# View background color and button image has the same code but different look (iOS)

Tags: ios, uiview

I set background color for UIView through storyboard, but I see brighter color in simulator. And it different with Button image background with the same code and sketch with the same code. Alpha set 1.
What can be wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sometimes you need to set the RGB to their natural state try using "generic RGB" in the colour settings

[image]

Comment: When I switch to Generic RGB HEX Code change from F37C7C to ED6569, if I correct it back to F37C7C, Generic RGB change to sRGB

Comment: Try to use the RGB you want with generic RGB, then you'll get the HEX code you want.

Comment: @WalterWest your solution worked, converting to rgb to srgb works like charm