# Asssigning tint color for navigation bar in storyboard assigns wrong color

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6

I'm trying to set navigation bar color to my color.

I do it in storyboard.

I set the color I want, like so:

[image]

And then this is what happens:

The color is completely off, both in app and in storyboard. How do I fix that?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are different RGB mode in Xcode,check if both rgb mode match.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you need generic RGB - already answered `-`

[View background color and button image has the same code but different look (iOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31050984/view-background-color-and-button-image-has-the-same-code-but-different-look-ios/31054376#31054376)